# Laravel Horizon Empty Dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

Laravel Horizon is showing an empty dashboard on a fresh installation. I followed the steps from laravel.com. I also tried to install it on different servers, but same issue persists.

No problem with packages or anything else. But, when I access the dashboard, nothing appears!

And there are no errors in the error logs.

Chrome's console is showing the errors below:

> GET http://178.62.204.162/vendor/horizon/css/app.css?id=5ce9973b1bc9f6a46cb2 404 (Not Found)
>   horizon:6
>
> GET http://178.62.204.162/vendor/horizon/js/app.js?id=1cfbba1e25ed49885098 404 (Not Found)
>   horizon:18

Comment: Check with your `.htaccess` file .

Comment: i haven't made any changes and all other things are working in this application. Also queue is working perfectly with redis.

Comment: Does theses files exists?

Comment: No. These files exist in [IP/public/vendor/horizon] folder. But there is no option to change its path without touching vendors folder or may be i don't know about that...

Comment: How are you accessing your website? through wamp (or any other dev plateform)? Or with the `php artisan serve` command ?

Comment: it's a production platform. I have tested it by installing new laravel instances on different production machines but facing same issue.

Comment: Ok, but you're accessing your website like this : `http://178.62.204.162/public` if I understand correctly your `[IP/public/vendor/horizon]` Because `/public` **should'nt** be a part of the URL.

Comment: I have tried both (with public on different machine and without public on different). :(
Here is the link (http://203.128.6.214/laravel/horizon). You can see the errors in console.

Comment: Can you check the file and folder permissions ?

Comment: Folders are on 755 and files 644

Comment: Your files are served at this address : http://203.128.6.214/laravel/public/vendor/horizon/css/app.css `/laravel/public` shouldn't be here at all. it's really seems to be a problem of configuration with the webroot. On localhost it's recommanded to uses the command `php artisan serve` or even better, a virtualhost pointing on your `public` folder and on production to point your domain on the `public` folder

Comment: @cbaconnier thank you for helping me. Actually horizon is only working with `php artisan serve` and before i had moved my index file from public to main directory. You can suggest me a better way to run project without `serve` on server.

Comment: _and before i had moved my index file from public to main directory_ Why would you do that ? The `public` directory should be the only entry point. As I said earlier, I suggest for your local dev a **virtualhost** or [valet on mac](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet) [valet on linux](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux) or [valet on windows](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows). On production, your domain name has to point on `htdocsOrWhatever/YourProject/public`

Comment: Thanks alot. I appreciates your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running project like `http://localhost/horizondemo/public/horizon` or `http://localhost/horizondemo/horizon` please try running with command `php artisan serve` will help here

Answer (score 0):

Horizion puts files into your `public/vendor` directory (such as the ones you mentioned, `app.css` and `app.js`), under its own `horizon` directory. These files must be accessible to the browser, so make sure requests to your web server at `/vendor` go to `public/vendor` in your project.